# Neo4j : Apply node similarity (NS) algorithm after calling weakly connected component (WCC) algorithm

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I would like to call NS algorithm after calling WCC. Here is what I did:

1. I created an in memory graph:

   `CALL gds.graph.create('my-graph','*','APPEARS_IN') YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;`
2. I ran WCC algorithm:

`CALL gds.wcc.write('my-graph', {writeProperty:'familyComponent'}) YIELD componentCount, nodePropertiesWritten;`

3. I created an other in memory graph to only keep the big network in my database:

`CALL gds.graph.create.cypher( 'myGraph_39','MATCH (n) WHERE n.familyComponent = 0 RETURN id(n) as id','MATCH (a:ARTICLE)<-[:APPEARS_IN]-(b:KEYWORD) RETURN id(b) AS source, id(a) AS target',{validateRelationships: false})YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;`

Here is the result of the code in 3):

[image]

4. I would like to call node similarity algorithm on this new graph because it  only contains the big network. But I don't know if it is possible.

I tought about creating a new database with this graph in 3) but it doesn't work.

What can I do ?

Comment: #4: Have you tried it?

Comment: Call the NS on the new graph I don't know how to do it. But I tried to create a database with the graph in 3) but it's not possible because I did a cypher projection to create the graph. According to the documentation it only works with gds.graph.create and not with gds.graph.create.cypher

Comment: It works either way, with native and cypher projection. Check https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2020/05/12/nlp-and-graphs-go-hand-in-hand-with-neo4j-and-apoc/ for an example

Comment: Thank you very much